# How to resolve: error: failed processing manifest

Tags: android, xml, cordova, ionic-framework, moodle-mobile

I am new to ***Ionic***, ***Android*** and ***Moodle***, I have several errors when trying to generate a custom **Moodle apk**, I come here for help for this error that is generated with the application ID.

Well, what I did was the following, I changed the original Moodle ID to my application, I was fixing errors with Grandle, I configured the SDK well, I linked the JDK, I built, compiled and transpiled very many times and that's why now I only fit the command directly.

I suspect that it may be an error in the config.xml, I don't know, or the folders created by changing the name of the id_app with the packages.

These errors appear in the console after executing `cordova.cmd build android --release`

```
[...]
> Task :app:processDebugResources
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Android resource linking failed
  C:\..\moodleapp\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:76: AAPT: error: resource xml/provider_paths (aka com.mycustom.app:xml/provider_paths) not found.

  C:\..\moodleapp\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:85: AAPT: error: resource xml/camera_provider_paths (aka com.mycustom.app:xml/camera_provider_paths) not found.

  C:\..\moodleapp\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:99: AAPT: error: resource xml/opener_paths (aka com.mycustom.app:xml/opener_paths) not found.

  error: failed processing manifest.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10s
 FAILED
23 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 22 up-to-date
C:\..\moodleapp\platforms\android\gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Android resource linking failed
  C:\..\moodleapp\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:76: AAPT: error: resource xml/provider_paths (aka com.mycustom.app:xml/provider_paths) not found.

  C:\..\moodleapp\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:85: AAPT: error: resource xml/camera_provider_paths (aka com.mycustom.app:xml/camera_provider_paths) not found.

  C:\..\moodleapp\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:99: AAPT: error: resource xml/opener_paths (aka com.mycustom.app:xml/opener_paths) not found.

  error: failed processing manifest.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10s
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

        cordova.cmd build android --buildFlag=-UseModernBuildSystem=0 exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.

C:\..\moodleapp>_
```

My Moodle AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" 
        android:versionCode="10000" 
        android:versionName="1.0" 
        package="com.mycustom.app" 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            [...more code...]
        <provider android:authorities="${applicationId}.darryncampbell.cordova.plugin.intent.fileprovider" 
        android:exported="false" 
        android:grantUriPermissions="true" 
        android:name="com.darryncampbell.cordova.plugin.intent.CordovaPluginIntentFileProvider">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" 
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>
        <provider android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false" 
            android:grantUriPermissions="true" 
            android:name="org.apache.cordova.camera.FileProvider">
                <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" 
                android:resource="@xml/camera_provider_paths" />
        </provider>
            <meta-data android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_deactivated" 
            android:value="true" />
        <provider android:authorities="${applicationId}.opener.provider" 
            android:exported="false" 
            android:grantUriPermissions="true" 
            android:name="io.github.pwlin.cordova.plugins.fileopener2.FileProvider">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" 
            android:resource="@xml/opener_paths" />
        </provider>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</manifest>
```

I just want to generate the apk and the steps of the moodle documentation has nt been useful to me.

link Moodle App https://github.com/moodlehq/moodleapp

My Proyect https://github.com/sauta/moodleapp

Doc Moodle APP https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Setting_up_your_development_environment_for_Moodle_Mobile_2#Building_for_Android_and_iOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like you miss some files.

you need to add this ressources into your config.xml, but first find the files in the explorer and write to real path instead of res/xml/ .

Source :

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/plugin_ref/spec.html#resource-file

```
<platform name="android">
  <resource-file src="res/xml/opener_paths.xml" target="res/xml/opener_paths.xml" />
  <resource-file src="res/xml/camera_provider_paths.xml" target="res/xml/camera_provider_paths.xml" />
  <resource-file src="res/xml/provider_paths.xml" target="res/xml/provider_paths.xml" />
</platform>
```

Comment: I did what you said, and I had a different result when I added
 the 3 lines of  `<resourcer-file/>` with their patches and replaced the `res/xml` for `@xml/` in _config.xml_ this is my result `AndroidManifest.xml:115: AAPT: error: unexpected element <resource-file> found in <manifest><application>.` i don't know i did to  bad. another route I found was `src/res/ xml`

Comment: change the `res/xml` to `@xml`